# Image for Google Card- How can I tell it is correctly 16:9 ratio?

Tags: google, google-material-design

Going by google design, I need my media section of a card(which is the image showing my website) to be 16:9 ratio. I'm using CSS to do this. How can I tell if media part(*the image portion*) this is correctly 16:9 ratio?

Note: The image itself needs to be 16:9, not the whole card. Also, I use Linux and do not own any Adobe products.

[image: The image portion needs to be 16:9 ratio]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that the image width relates to the height as the number 16 relates to the number 9.

16 divided by 9 is 1.77777778. That means that your image width must be 1.77777778 times larger than the height.

E.g. an image with the width of 800px should be 450px high.

Comment: Not true.  You can't use pixels for this ratio because mobile devices can be rotated from a 16:9 to a 9:16 (or similar).  For SVG and CSS, this is easy to fix because you can use a multiple of 16mm by 9mm.

Comment: I don't think your case is applicable to the question. If you rotate a device, the image ratio stays the same. This is intended.